# Why does an explosion on the surface remove ground underneath it, creating a crater?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics

Why do bombs exploding on earth surfaces typically create a crater?

An explosion on the surface of a compressible ground creates a depression by compressing the ground.
An explosion on the surface that can be deformed creates a depression by displacing material, like creating a dent in a steel plate, if that steel does not rupture.

But an explosion on earth surface creates a crater by moving material sideways and upwards, removing material under the explosion. If ground is not normally elastic, and can not be compressed or pressed down, how does that work?

Is it that natural ground always has one of these properties, or is it an unrelated effect?

Comment: It might help you to imagine the explosion as a point source with arrows emerging in all directions radially.  That way, it's easy to see that the forces from the explosion almost all have a component pointing away from the point source and parallel to the surface of the ground.   There are other factors as well, but that alone will force some of the earth to move sideways away from the explosion.

Comment: Also note, If you are talking about craters made by artillery shells or by bombs that were dropped from airplanes, then your assumption that the bomb exploded on the surface may not be correct. In England and in Europe, they still sometimes find unexploded bombs that have lain buried in the ground since WWII. https://www.nottinghampost.com/news/nottingham-news/live-long-eaton-bomb-police-3236314

Comment: @SolomonSlow I can confirm that. In Berlin, about 100 m from the house I live in, one of them was dug out not long ago. The police rings, explains the mandatory evacuation for three ours or so, you go shopping. Back, you see a big dump truck with sand driving away, sand and a defused bomb. It was 2 m or so deep, found when working on a water pipe an the sidewalk.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Even more off topic, but worth telling in this context, because I assume you are in the UK: The psychology of it is interesting: I'm German, born after the war. I am sitting at a place that would be hit by glass pieces, if the bomb had exploded. And I feel neutral about it. I think it was dropped by the RAF. No negative feelings, I could be friends withe person who dropped it. It was the right thing to do.